# OVerfitting using Random Forest - classification

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, random-forest, overfitting

I have a dataframe which is a made of many datasets combined together (many datasets with the same predictive features but with different samples combined together). This dataframe, called `scoresWithResponse` , contains the target feature (binary feature, Response / NoResponse) along with many predictive features. The features are in the columns, and the samples are the rows.

The problem is I got an accuracy of 1 in the training set, AUC = 1.

I am using cross validation, and I did feature seletion by calculating the correlation of each predictive feature with the target feature (dropped the number of predictive features from 38 to 26), still the accuracy and precision are 1, a massive overfitting situation and I don't know what is causing this.

The data is imbalanced but not severely. Class `NoResponse` have about 900 samples and class `Response` about 550 samples. So not that imbalanced.

Is there any tool in R that I can use to fix this?

#### This is a sample of the `scoresWithResponse` df. The target feature is called `response`:

```
structure(list(response = c("NoResponse", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", 
"NoResponse", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", 
"NoResponse", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", 
"NoResponse", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", 
"NoResponse", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", 
"NoResponse", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", 
"NoResponse", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", 
"NoResponse", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", 
"NoResponse", "Response", "Response", "Response", "Response", 
"Response", "Response", "Response", "Response", "Response", "Response", 
"NoResponse"), Adipocytes = c(-0.00147259448084057, -0.00147259448084057, 
-0.00147259448084057, -0.00147259448084057, 0.00496131218358668, 
0.0548062334131809, -0.00147259448084057, -0.00147259448084057, 
-0.00147259448084057, 0.179318801379469, -0.00147259448084057, 
0.0152373546449648, 0.00471475971580131, -0.00147259448084057, 
-0.00147259448084057, -0.00147259448084057, 0.0223344650075101, 
-0.00147259448084057, 0.440899655514849, -0.00147259448084057, 
-0.00147259448084057, -0.00147259448084057, -0.00147259448084057, 
0.00667190889349088, 0.0209909859594865, -0.00147259448084057, 
0.141500721589385, 0.3787676219377, -0.00147259448084057, 0.100845895196263, 
0.00376639229249542, -0.00147259448084057, -0.00147259448084057, 
-0.00147259448084057, -0.00147259448084057, -0.00147259448084057, 
-0.00147259448084057, -0.00147259448084057, -0.00147259448084057, 
0.0143591851858567, 0.029973315783053, 0.109643119475897, -0.00147259448084057, 
-0.00147259448084057, 0.033995214866229, -0.00147259448084057, 
-0.00147259448084057, 0.00729426178712381, -0.00147259448084057, 
0.0117856592972338), B.cells = c(0.0784674365204107, 0.0361475824469536, 
1.23322306963728, 0.168147773376171, 0.0303336417563689, 0.030213842229231, 
0.0104772945803579, 0.6165526362465, 0.0558472468040232, 0.199731757583661, 
0.0332625376923969, 0.0254342545665831, 0.0814952345178611, 0.0571654345486949, 
0.0104772945803579, 0.0384667823875126, 0.0992166491520768, 0.0909511066706036, 
0.0417584790221351, 0.0104772945803579, 0.0168983625736141, 0.0104772945803579, 
0.0205640352085533, 0.0356276975652135, 0.118678007191133, 0.0254963339043755, 
0.0335184044896974, 0.133580305750364, 0.0629651829274283, 0.0104772945803579, 
0.0577719570574633, 0.0354883966171345, 0.0584470348183582, 0.0104772945803579, 
0.0478863386113402, 0.0217393584085478, 0.583228651740994, 0.0104772945803579, 
0.0433224106904174, 0.0344094787634546, 0.046651993965254, 0.0104772945803579, 
0.0104772945803579, 0.0104772945803579, 0.0104772945803579, 0.0426020746172987, 
0.060934091547895, 0.0550381273743561, 0.0331768751035052, 0.465658884141495
), Basophils = c(0.078906060975291, 0.185474445082498, 0.134401186945301, 
0.665820958289465, 0.0658110816910161, 0.549145210521612, 0.127165943704943, 
0.0388563858940922, 0.12506366351286, 0.0687444342155732, 0.128218399654121, 
0.264632805160075, 0.111198850866759, 0.0740271877643854, 0.0547830059780378, 
0.0788819375423888, 0.122504718666759, 0.116646155897171, 0.0388563858940922, 
0.0388563858940922, 0.0847087204695266, 0.170267877921665, 0.192990813992193, 
0.08636451452274, 0.205951716498705, 0.0712175634510349, 0.0783020221825332, 
0.139422879181795, 0.155482339672933, 0.0388563858940922, 0.110246668069126, 
0.110815958263559, 0.332485196949693, 0.0658358036825454, 0.0388563858940922, 
0.0790990677422829, 0.0388563858940922, 0.0685108479102874, 0.0603506212082886, 
0.0458583547445136, 0.124593010554148, 0.157943929160168, 0.0388563858940922, 
0.0388563858940922, 0.0769474587712551, 0.184789379564458, 0.141639474022545, 
0.112218409146376, 0.0886279736342864, 0.141914971660106), CD4..naive.T.cells = c(0.000352118916979948, 
0.000352118916979948, 0.195806941197775, 0.000352118916979948, 
0.000352118916979948, 0.000352118916979948, 0.000352118916979948, 
0.00671990447291144, 0.000352118916979948, 0.000352118916979948, 
0.000352118916979948, 0.000352118916979948, 0.000352118916979948, 
0.000352118916979948, 0.000352118916979948, 0.000352118916979948, 
0.000352118916979948, 0.000352118916979948, 0.000352118916979948, 
0.000352118916979948, 0.000352118916979948, 0.000352118916979948, 
0.000352118916979948, 0.000352118916979948, 0.000352118916979948, 
0.000352118916979948, 0.000352118916979948, 0.000352118916979948, 
0.000352118916979948, 0.000352118916979948, 0.000352118916979948, 
0.000352118916979948, 0.000352118916979948, 0.000352118916979948, 
0.000352118916979948, 0.000352118916979948, 0.038732799099841, 
0.000352118916979948, 0.000352118916979948, 0.000352118916979948, 
0.000352118916979948, 0.000352118916979948, 0.000352118916979948, 
0.000352118916979948, 0.0101707970144034, 0.000352118916979948, 
0.000352118916979948, 0.000352118916979948, 0.000352118916979948, 
0.0259073784136612), CD4..Tcm = c(0.00468132560940506, 0.00468132560940506, 
0.0229444590832302, 0.00468132560940506, 0.00468132560940506, 
0.00468132560940506, 0.00468132560940506, 0.00468132560940506, 
0.00468132560940506, 0.00468132560940506, 0.00468132560940506, 
0.00468132560940506, 0.00468132560940506, 0.00468132560940506, 
0.00468132560940506, 0.00468132560940506, 0.00468132560940506, 
0.00468132560940506, 0.00468132560940506, 0.00468132560940506, 
0.00468132560940506, 0.00468132560940506, 0.00468132560940506, 
0.00468132560940506, 0.00468132560940506, 0.00468132560940506, 
0.00468132560940506, 0.00468132560940506, 0.00468132560940506, 
0.00468132560940506, 0.00468132560940506, 0.00468132560940506, 
0.00468132560940506, 0.00468132560940506, 0.00468132560940506, 
0.00468132560940506, 0.00468132560940506, 0.00468132560940506, 
0.00468132560940506, 0.00468132560940506, 0.00468132560940506, 
0.00468132560940506, 0.00468132560940506, 0.00468132560940506, 
0.00468132560940506, 0.00468132560940506, 0.00468132560940506, 
0.00468132560940506, 0.013310582713857, -0.0341347438586641), 
    CD8..T.cells = c(0.0674507123528756, 0.0333806083003552, 
    0.346632430262511, 0.0651318726541825, 0.05791288966358, 
    0.0333806083003552, 0.0333806083003552, 0.145972600599313, 
    0.0455590324140021, 0.0557212756574658, 0.0458694514125555, 
    0.0333806083003552, 0.070967388083968, 0.0333806083003552, 
    0.0333806083003552, 0.0333806083003552, 0.0841865232673732, 
    0.169166782933996, 0.0333806083003552, 0.0508094953191331, 
    0.0333806083003552, 0.0333806083003552, 0.0333806083003552, 
    0.0836162747296847, 0.0533760632756103, 0.0333806083003552, 
    0.0333806083003552, 0.159932930078836, 0.105368013137071, 
    0.0333806083003552, 0.0790884230508081, 0.0333806083003552, 
    0.0333806083003552, 0.0333806083003552, 0.0437642832942929, 
    0.0333806083003552, 0.22743171311185, 0.0333806083003552, 
    0.0333806083003552, 0.0661391850408331, 0.0333806083003552, 
    0.0333806083003552, 0.0333806083003552, 0.0333806083003552, 
    0.0333806083003552, 0.0333806083003552, 0.12082525756811, 
    0.0490077373424495, 0.0333806083003552, 0.240026829190165
    ), CD8..Tcm = c(0.193057099564419, 0.022148022736091, 0.505616937986011, 
    0.238282112180758, 0.0802713022259099, 0.0342057097559616, 
    0.022148022736091, 0.258249161888649, 0.150220291489214, 
    0.167072217214248, 0.0300146589259272, 0.022148022736091, 
    0.0793499984509763, 0.0346033174041023, 0.022148022736091, 
    0.022148022736091, 0.123946309722711, 0.36610054169658, 0.0370798548885808, 
    0.022148022736091, 0.022148022736091, 0.022148022736091, 
    0.0339040869679633, 0.154406584553023, 0.177613519349749, 
    0.04051161748082, 0.0909580697983234, 0.293962482478071, 
    0.157866758221804, 0.0296400174109871, 0.151550569935703, 
    0.022148022736091, 0.0621661868212978, 0.022148022736091, 
    0.0987008846736535, 0.022148022736091, 0.366709884745067, 
    0.022148022736091, 0.0402905235116509, 0.0948609973244887, 
    0.0569280565039912, 0.022148022736091, 0.022148022736091, 
    0.0309187098761019, 0.022148022736091, 0.112148244674048, 
    0.220105996648614, 0.0934563517188017, 0.022148022736091, 
    0.343363303326582), Class.switched.memory.B.cells = c(0.0487914604272673, 
    0.0411529688937465, 0.335591478817477, 0.0310529711582873, 
    0.0310529711582873, 0.0310529711582873, 0.0310529711582873, 
    0.182205893480734, 0.052142399620452, 0.123251255694447, 
    0.0534870034377551, 0.0555369571975287, 0.0548278202087546, 
    0.0310529711582873, 0.0310529711582873, 0.0310529711582873, 
    0.0310529711582873, 0.104615136743085, 0.0435557901247572, 
    0.0429005295010426, 0.0310529711582873, 0.0310529711582873, 
    0.0310529711582873, 0.038962823575526, 0.0988525482538249, 
    0.0539200343035075, 0.0310529711582873, 0.0651637094528887, 
    0.0310529711582873, 0.0566023036659616, 0.0496492442525651, 
    0.0310529711582873, 0.0634323182972408, 0.0310529711582873, 
    0.0310529711582873, 0.0310529711582873, 0.167624227076226, 
    0.0310529711582873, 0.0310529711582873, 0.0310529711582873, 
    0.0310529711582873, 0.0371717851391283, 0.0483888468863344, 
    0.0941646814676068, 0.0310529711582873, 0.0310529711582873, 
    0.0310529711582873, 0.0364758992300671, 0.0410986750456075, 
    0.133092168173884), DC = c(0.0664041472178045, 0.001974947933282, 
    0.0526951586016229, 0.135108924806137, 0.0133056050961418, 
    0.0775815332310746, 0.001974947933282, 0.0369699850727529, 
    0.0214395600577855, 0.0339845994266395, 0.0111625280105067, 
    0.001974947933282, 0.0186918493607988, 0.0333206480825139, 
    0.0102856708829166, 0.001974947933282, 0.0498326250235207, 
    0.0364369465986278, 0.0723203591042894, 0.0423329199616102, 
    0.001974947933282, 0.001974947933282, 0.001974947933282, 
    0.0556268755782605, 0.0660946770036415, 0.0741807202880026, 
    0.0308137087616544, 0.0760961528436393, 0.0143083258007051, 
    0.0127495162722945, 0.0431798081217165, 0.001974947933282, 
    0.0170564729518741, 0.0121701726086785, 0.001974947933282, 
    0.001974947933282, 0.0609445697531212, 0.001974947933282, 
    0.001974947933282, 0.0324793759855767, 0.0228625916874287, 
    0.001974947933282, 0.001974947933282, 0.019310419413258, 
    0.0232906676085244, 0.0758116669022375, 0.04027829659775, 
    0.0204012723800148, 0.001974947933282, 0.0257352602124135
    )), row.names = c("Pt1", "Pt10", "Pt101", "Pt103", "Pt106", 
"Pt11", "Pt17", "Pt18", "Pt2", "Pt24", "Pt26", "Pt27", "Pt28", 
"Pt29", "Pt3", "Pt30", "Pt31", "Pt34", "Pt36", "Pt37", "Pt38", 
"Pt39", "Pt4", "Pt44", "Pt46", "Pt47", "Pt48", "Pt49", "Pt5", 
"Pt52", "Pt59", "Pt62", "Pt65", "Pt66", "Pt67", "Pt72", "Pt77", 
"Pt78", "Pt79", "Pt8", "Pt82", "Pt84", "Pt85", "Pt89", "Pt9", 
"Pt90", "Pt92", "Pt94", "Pt98", "EA595454"), class = "data.frame")
```

#### This is the code:

```
library(caret)
library(MLeval)
library(DMwR2)
library(predtools)

cancer.type = totaldata$Cancer_Type
scores.batch = limma::removeBatchEffect(Scores ,cancer.type)

scoresWithResponse = data.frame(response = as.factor(totaldata$Response=='Response'),t(scores.batch))
scoresWithResponse$response = plyr::mapvalues(scoresWithResponse$response, c('TRUE', 'FALSE'), c('Response', 'NoResponse'))

corVec = sapply(scoresWithResponse[-1], ltm::biserial.cor, scoresWithResponse[[1]])
vc = corVec > 0.01 | corVec < -0.02

scoresWithResponse = scoresWithResponse[,names(vc[vc==T])]
scoresWithResponse$response = data$response
scoresWithResponse$response = plyr::mapvalues(scoresWithResponse$response, c('1','0'), c('Response', 'NoResponse'))
scoresWithResponse = scoresWithResponse %>% dplyr::select(response, everything())

training = createDataPartition(y = scoresWithResponse$response, p=0.8, list = FALSE)
scoresWithResponse.trn = scoresWithResponse[training, ]
scoresWithResponse.tst = scoresWithResponse[-training,]

ctrlCV = trainControl(method = 'cv', number = 10 , classProbs = TRUE , savePredictions = TRUE)

rfFit <- train(response~., data = scoresWithResponse.trn,
               importance = TRUE,
               method = "rf",
               #ntree = 100,
               metric="ROC",
               trControl = ctrlCV,
               tuneLength = 20,

)


rfROC = roc(scoresWithResponse.trn$response,predict(rfFit,scoresWithResponse.trn, type='prob')[,1])
plot(rfROC)
auc(rfROC)

print(rfFit)
plot(rfFit) # best mtry in x axis
rfFit$results

pred1 = predict(rfFit, scoresWithResponse.trn)
confusionMatrix(table(scoresWithResponse.trn[,'response'], pred1))

tst1 = predict(rfFit, scoresWithResponse.tst)
confusionMatrix(table(scoresWithResponse.tst[,'response'], tst1))
```

#### A picture showing the ROC curve of the training set:

[image]

Comment: I have voted to close, basically the same question has been asked before. As far as we can see from the question, there's nothing to fix here (other than your understanding of the model): randomForests are *designed* to perfectly fit their training data, and looking at training performance is therefore not suitable to infer anything about overfitting.

Answer (score 2):

Random forests are notorious for overfitting.   Univariate screening of variables before running RF is not at all appropriate.  RF (which requires **enormous** sample sizes to be successful) requires access to all of the **candidate** predictors.  Univariate screening may be used because of a perception of helping with overfitting but it just makes things works and can result in missing predictors that are important only after adjusting for other predictors.  Looking at class imbalance is not appropriate but may be indicating to us that you are using a discontinuous accuracy scoring rule such as proportion "classified" "correctly".  Use probabilities of class membership and associated proper accuracy scores.

Ill effects of univariate screening are even worse if this screening was not repeated afresh at each cross-validation step.

Comment: So if I understand correctly what you're saying, prefarably I should not use feature selection, and that I should not evaluate the model based on the number of samples classified correctly. is that right? and could you please elaborate a bit more about univariate screening? what do you mean by that? and what evaluations should I use then? I didn't get that part. Thank you so much sir.

Comment: Univariate screening is where you computed the correlation of each feature separately, with the target variable.  Yes use an approach made for probabilities, not forced-choice classifications.  E.g. Brier score, deviance, pseudo $R^2$ - see e.g. https://fharrell.com/post/addvalue

Comment: I'd say randomForests are *designed to perfectly fit the training data*. Whether they also overfit (as in: having bad generalization ability) is an entirely different question which cannot be answered by training data performance. (My *guess* is that since the shown code shows some batch effect treatment, and the rF is not taking into account batches, that it is quite likely to overfit - but that won't be detected unless the partitioning splits of test batches) ...

Comment: ...   (+1) for pointing OP to inappropriate screening, better figures of merit and the need to properly position pre-treatment/data-driven selection inside the CV loop.